# facebook connect pluggin in cakephp

Tags: facebook, cakephp

I am using "webtechnick CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin" for my site for login and authentication. My site is in cakephp. I have placed the plugin in proper folder as guided in the video. But when I am running my site I am getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::login() in 
/home/depasser/public_html/var/www/html/fb_app/app/views/elements/login.ctp on line 12
```

I have tried a lot to solve this issue but haven't succeeded. Can anyone guide me how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You should post your `/views/elements/login.ctp` code so we can analyse it...

Answer (score 0):

Is the helper in your controller for this view, if the 'Facebook.Facebook' helper is not there it wont work.